# Firebird and Generate Views in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, linq, firebird, edmx, entity-framework-6.1

I already have runnning EF6 (Firebird provider 4.5) in VS 2013 and there is a single fix to solve. Generate Views of Power Tools Beta 4 shows this message when called to run T4 process:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
Framework.edmx(7,6) : **error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.**
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Utilities.EdmxUtility.GetMappingCollectionEF6(Assembly ef6Assembly, String& containerName)
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.OptimizeContextHandler.OptimizeEdmx(String inputPath)
```

My guess is: EntityFramework.Firebird must be placed where Generate Views runs, where it is installed. What is this path? Where is Generate Views running? EntityFramework.Firebird is addressed at entityFramework but I guess that Power Tools look at machine.config but EntityFramework.Firebird can't be there.

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" 
            type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Thanks,

Marco Castro

Comment: I tested it on my VS2012 and it works. Ss the Firebird DDEX provider installed? You also need the EF provider 4.5 in the GAC to get it working inside the VS.

Comment: DDEX is installed and FireBird 4.5 is installed in GAC.

Comment: Try install again, but choose the option CHANGE and see if the VS2012,2013 OS64x and OS86x is installed too. If not, install them and just enjoy.